# FileNotFoundException - no file missing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, filenotfoundexception

When entering a view for the first time, this exception is raised:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

First of all - why would it just happen the first time I enter that specific view? Even IF the issue was in the constructor (which it could not be), it would be called (and the exception thrown) every time I enter the view.

Second of all - how would I find the source of such an exception? It doesn't break into the debugger, and there are no resource files (like background images, app bar icons) missing.

Lastly - what (except directly referencing files in the code) would throw such an exception?

I would show you the code in question, but the file is a bit too big to post all of it.

**UPDATE:**

After debugging, I have noticed that the error happens *after* the constructor and `OnNavigatedTo()` and *before* `Loaded()`. There is a thread being launched in the OnNavigatedTo method, but I have tried to try-catch every single element of that part (and every internal part of it), and no error was found.

**UPDATE 2:**

After debugging some more, I found the error message:

> File or assembly name 'System.Windows.debug.resources, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

Also the stack trace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.throwVersion37CompatException(ExceptionType newEType,
    String newString, ExceptionType oldEType, String oldString)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
at System.Windows.Resx..ctor()
at System.Windows.Resx.GetLoader()
at System.Windows.Resx.GetStringHelper(String name)
at System.Windows.Resx.GetString(String name)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.ToString()
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj,
    IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex,
    Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Comment: Hard to answer without code, stacktrace...etc.

Comment: I know - but in general, what would throw such an exception (except directly referencing files in XAML, code)?

Comment: Does it happen when you run the application normally or just while debugging?

Comment: Usually its a path issue, or, a what directory you think its in, compared to where it actually is..

Comment: @svinja - Both in debug and release builds (on emulator and on device) both with breakpoints and not.

Comment: Obviously just one line of code makes this happen - if the entire code is too long, just paste the relevant code lines(a bit before and a bit after this exception).

Comment: catch and .ToString() the exception, the resulting text should contain a reference to the throwing line.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a DLL that needs to be included in order to use that library.

Comment: I have found out some new details around where it happens, see original question for details.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can set break for the first chance exception visual studio, debug in to see the detail about the FileNotFound exception, which file is missing.
2. sometime, clr try to find some extension dll, which is normally too magic to us.  for example, if you use XmlSerialize in your project, if you don't use sgen.exe to generate the dynamic xml serialize dll for your serializble type, CLR will generate one during runtime, but before this, clr will try to load the assemble, which will cause FileNotFoundException, but catched

Comment: see this link:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657648/filenotfoundexception-in-silverlight-for-wp7